# Redirecting apt-get output

Tags: command-line, apt, patch, redirect

So there's some output from apt-get that I can't seem to redirect anywhere else. Here's a sample of what I see:

```
sudo apt-get -qq -y --force-yes install cowsay 2>&1 > /tmp/tmp.txt
```

This is a sample command that I'm running on 16.04. I'm including the `--force-yes` here to simulate an apt warning for future use. now I expect this command to redirect everything to `/tmp/tmp.txt` ; and most of the code is doing this. However when I run it I get the following:

```
$ sudo apt-get -qq -y --force-yes remove cowsay 2>&1 > /tmp/tmp.txt
W: --force-yes is deprecated, use one of the options starting with --allow instead.
```

How do I get warnings to redirect to my file too?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have the stream redirection command in the wrong place. Redirections get parsed from right to left, therefore you need to first write the `> /tmp/tmp.txt` and then the `2>&1`. As you wrote it, it first redirects STDOUT to the file and afterwards redirects STDERR to STDOUT.

This is the correct command:

```
sudo apt-get -qq -y --force-yes remove cowsay > /tmp/tmp.txt 2>&1
```

But there's a simpler alternative! You don't necessarily need to redirect STDERR into STDOUT to get both written into a file, there's also an operator that directly redirects both STDOUT and STDERR to a file: `&>`

```
sudo apt-get -qq -y --force-yes remove cowsay &> /tmp/tmp.txt
```

Explanation and further info:

- `> filename` redirects STDOUT (stream 1) to `filename`
- `2> filename` redirects STDERR (stream 2) to `filename`
- `&> filename` redirects STDOUT and STDERR to `filename`

Similarly if you want to pipe the output to a second command:

- `|` redirects STDOUT (stream 1) to the second command's STDIN
- `2| filename` redirects STDERR (stream 2) to the second command's STDIN
- `&| filename` redirects STDOUT and STDERR to the second command's STDIN

Comment: That did it. Thanks! It would have taken me ages to figure this out.